# Zookeeper API change from 3.4.6 to 3.5.5

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am working on Zookeeper upgrade from 3.4.6 to 3.5.5.
Since org.apache.zookeeper.data package is removed from 3.5.5 I am looking for alternative API.

mvn compilation is failing for below two classes

org.apache.zookeeper.data.ACL and org.apache.zookeeper.data.Stat

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you conclude that those two packages are removed for later versions of ZooKeeper, this is not the case. However, during the documentation generation for later versions, there is no link for those packages because they are now defined using Jute and not pure java. So to find such documentation, check here:

https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/apidocs/zookeeper-jute/

Answer (score 0):

Go into 'zookeeper-jute' project and run "maven generate-sources".
Assuming: Your on eclipse and opened project from parent folder.